# Submitting first job to pacemaker

Tags: linux, server, submission, pacemaker

I followed this guide:
https://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/

I stayed with the Active/Passive DRBD file system sharing.  I had to reboot my cluster and now I am getting the following error:

```
Current DC: rbx-1 (version 1.1.16-12.el7_4.4-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Nov 28 17:01:14 2017
Last change: Tue Nov 28 16:40:09 2017 by root via cibadmin on rbx-1

2 nodes configured
5 resources configured

Node rbx-2: UNCLEAN (offline)
Online: [ rbx-1 ]

Full list of resources:

 ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started rbx-1
 WebSite    (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Stopped
 Master/Slave Set: WebDataClone [WebData]
     WebData    (ocf::linbit:drbd): FAILED rbx-1 (blocked)
     Stopped: [ rbx-2 ]
 WebFS  (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Stopped

Failed Actions:
* WebData_stop_0 on rbx-1 'invalid parameter' (2): call=20, status=complete, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Tue Nov 28 16:27:58 2017', queued=0ms, exec=3ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Any ideas?

Also does anyone have any recommended guides for submitting jobs?

Comment: I'm also getting this error: Warning: Agent 'ocf:linbit:drbd' is not installed or does not provide valid metadata: Metadata query for ocf:linbit:drbd failed: -5

Comment: What distro are you using? What does your Pacemaker configuration look like? The 'ocf:linbit:drbd' resource agent comes from drbd-utils, which you should have if you configured your DRBD device already (which you should have done).

Answer (score 0):

This post is relatively old at this point but I'll leave this here for others to find if they stumble upon the same issue.

This problem has to do with an issue with the DRBD integration script that pacemaker uses. If it's broken, missing, has incorrect permissions, etc. you can get an error like this. In CentOS 7 that script is located at **/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/drbd**

**Note: This is specifically for the guide mentioned by OP but may help you:**
Section 7.1 has a big "IMPORTANT" block that talks about replacing the Pacemaker integration script due to a bug. If you use the command it tells you to there, you actually replace the script with a 404 Error page which obviously doesn't work, causing the error. You can fix this issue by replacing the script with the original, either by reinstalling DRBD...

```
yum remove -y kmod-drbd84 drbd84-utils
yum install -y kmod-drbd84 drbd84-utils
```

...or finding just the drbd script elsewhere and adding/replacing it to /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/drbd. Make sure its permissions are correct and that it is set as executable.

Hope that helps!